# The new question list doesn't appear to be updating

Tags: bug, status-norepro, live-refresh

I noticed while browsing the SE app that all the newest questions were asked seven minutes ago. In case it was an API issue (pretty common), I loaded up the full (mobile) site, and it's the same (sorry about the borders, idk why those show up here):

[image]

This was taken right after a refresh (actually several).

Now, it's possible that no one asked a question in a whole seven minutes, but that seems extraordinarily unlikely. It seems new questions aren't showing up.

Comment: It does update when you select a tag.

Comment: @dfhwze Even after selecting a tag, the newest questions that are showing up are 11 minutes old.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, I see new questions come in just fine. Several came in while I was writing this comment, on main and on meta.

Comment: seems fine now, but I was able to reproduce it 7 minutes ago, both logged in and in private window on FF

Comment: Ya, it seems ok now. That was a long hiccup.